# Jquery/Javascript: Trying to stop subsequent if statements using booleans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to use a boolean to work with some if statements.
My code looks something like this:

```
let found = false

function myFunction() {
  if (found === false) {
    ($('#character').click(function() {
      $('#redBox').animate({
        right: '-=700px'
      });
      $("#redBox").css({
        backgroundColor: "grey"
      });
      $('#blueBox').animate({
        right: '-=700px'
      });
      $("#blueBox").css({
        backgroundColor: "grey"
      });
      found = true;
    }));
  };
}
}
myFunction();
if (found === false) {
  ($('#redBox').click(function() {
    $('#character').animate({
      right: '-=700px'
    });
    $("#character").css({
      backgroundColor: "grey"
    });
    $('#blueBox').animate({
      right: '-=700px'
    });
    $("#blueBox").css({
      backgroundColor: "grey"
    });
    found = true;
  }));
};
}
```

What I want to happen is have only one or the other of the if statements run.
So when I press one div (i.e #character) the boolean turns true preventing the other if statement from running.

However this is not happening and the unclicked if statements still run even though the boolean has turned true.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: You have some extra `}` characters.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around your `$(...).click()` functions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define the `.click()` behaviour **inside** of the conditional.

In order to only allow one click, what you need to do is swap your logic around, and set up a conditional for `found` inside of **each** of the `.click()` handlers:

```js
let found = false;

$("#character, #redBox").click(function() {
  if (found === false) {
    found = true;
    console.log("Clicked once");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="character">Character</div>
<div id="redBox">Red Box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the found variable is assigned at the time the click happens. At that point in time, you have already bound both event listeners to the elements and they will stay there until removed. If you only want one thing to ever happen, you need to do the if statement inside of the click.

```
    let found = false
function myFunction(){
    ($('#character').click(function(){
        if (found === false){
            $('#redBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
            $("#redBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
            $('#blueBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
            $("#blueBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
            found = true;
        }
    }));
}

myFunction();
($('#redBox').click(function(){
    if (found === false){
        $('#character').animate({right: '-=700px'});
        $("#character").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
        $('#blueBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
        $("#blueBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
        found = true;
    };
}));
```

but, if I may suggest, a better/cleaner structure for that might be:

```
    var fired = false;
$('#redBox, #character').click(function(e){
    if(! fired){
        fired = true;
        if(this.id === "redBox"){
            $('#character').animate({right: '-=700px'});
            $("#character").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
        }else{
            $('#redBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
            $("#redBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
        }
        $('#blueBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
        $("#blueBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
    }
});
```

additionally, you could get rid of the if statement all together, and just remove the event listener after the first time it is invoked. This has a positive impact on the page, because you aren't calling this function anymore for future clicks. Minimal in this instance, but good practice all the same:

```
$('#redBox, #character').on('click', function(e){
    if(this.id === "redBox"){
        $('#character').animate({right: '-=700px'});
        $("#character").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
    }else{
        $('#redBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
        $("#redBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});
    }
    $('#blueBox').animate({right: '-=700px'});
    $("#blueBox").css({backgroundColor: "grey"});

    $('#redBox, #character').off('click');//remove the event from #redBox and #character
});
```